# remove Azure Role Assignment for a set of users across different subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to delete the assigned roles for a set of users that I've in csv file:

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select -ExpandProperty SignInName
```

Then, I wanted to retrieve all the object Ids of these users so I run the following:

```
 foreach ($user in $Users)
 {
   $Users = (Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $User).Id
 }
```

Unfortunately, it only retrieves the id of 1 user not all the users in the sheet.
Finally, when I try to delete the role assignment for the generated result using the following Cmdlet:

```
Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $Users -RoleDefinitionName "*Owner*"
```

I get the following error:
Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment : The provided information does not map to a role assignment
Please advise why I only get one user after the loop and also, why I get that error.

**UPDATE**
In order to make sure that the script would delete the users from different subscriptions, I changed the script a little bit

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select -ExpandProperty SignInName
$Subs = (Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv').SubscriptionId

foreach ($sub in $Subs)
{
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $sub
    foreach ($user in $Users)
     {
        $OID = (Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $User).Id
        Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $OID.Guid -RoleDefinitionName Owner -Scope /subscriptions/$sub -Verbose
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:
Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment : The provided information does not map to a role assignment.

Comment: whatever you want to do, I think you should check the `foreach` loop carefully. Do you want to use `$User` in it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** So from your edits I don't think you get the idea of the ForEach. I will try to explain your ForEach edit for you at the end. But right now, this should work based on your info.

```
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv'

foreach ($user in $Users){
    Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Owner -SignInName $_.SignInName -Scope /subscriptions/$_.SubscriptionId -Verbose
}
```

Now, the problem with your edited code.

```
# The CSVs can be combined down to one and specific data pulled from them when needed.
$Users = Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv' | select -ExpandProperty SignInName
$Subs = (Import-Csv 'C:\Users.csv').SubscriptionId

# This says for each object in variable $subs...
foreach ($sub in $Subs)
{
    # Select the subscription - But do nothing with it cuz herp.
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $sub
    foreach ($user in $Users)
     {
        # Searches for the ObjectID of a User based on their SignInName (Email) and assigns to variable
        $OID = (Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $User).Id
        Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $OID.Guid -RoleDefinitionName Owner -Scope /subscriptions/$sub -Verbose
     }
}
```

Comment: Still does not work, because OID is empty. Also, in the same csv file I've thier subscription Ids. Can I automatically assign it to scope?

Comment: You most definitely can add it. What are the headers of you csv file? Without seeing that i am unsure what to use.

Comment: Completed an edit for you mate. Try to limit the amount of double ups you have. I recommend adding some write-host to your scripts as you play around with them so you can see exactly what data it is getting.

Comment: Thanks for your help Drew.
When I run the edit you have provided, I get the following error: Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SignInName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: What are the headers of your CSV file.

Comment: SignInName,SignInName, "Subscription Name"